# JWT / Stateless Architecture and large security Data

Tags: angular, security, jwt, stateless

I am a bit confused with the "statless" concept. I have a situation where my app is based on a stateless architecture. Authentication is made with JWT tokens ( no authentication providers like KeyCloack and OpenAM are used).

It is a simple mechansim where a front End logs to backend which answers with a JWT Token containing user data (including ID, roles ...).The token will be issued in the header of each http request.

Now other security concepts are involved ( apart from the roles we add a security on data). My problem is that the size can grow fast , even with a good security configuration (creating groups, hiding details inside the group, putting only group id in the token).

Since i am in a stateless context, each http request has to provide the security context so that the server can answer it.

Most servers have a 8K header size limit, and as far as i know it is recommended to put the JWT token in the header.

My question is how to make this work without compromising:
- Stateless architecture : Server must not store any session information.
- Identity : To execute a request, server has to know which roles and DATA scope the user can access to
- Header limit : which is 8K (i can increase but i dont think it is a good idea).

Thank you for your Help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I misunderstood your actual question, but you can make an interceptor which will attach token to headers if it's present in localStorage. And if you want to limit user abilities by role, you simply need to store some kind of a `currentUser` object in a singleton (service) where you will have all the data, like roles, etc. So there you can get this data in components, and check if currentUser is permitted to make changes or not. In this case you may limit user action to not allow make requests which are allowed only for authorized/granted users. Also, if there are some routes which shouldn't be accessible by all users, but only for an admin(for example), then you can make a route guard and use it on route in `canActivate`.  Would like to hear a bit more details, just in case I really misunderstood your question. And yeah this all makes sense only if that `security data` is provided in jwt token, or you are able to request it and store in your `currentUser` object which will be cleaned on `logout()` event, or when server will respond with 401, 403 errors. Hope at least some of the points here will be helpful.

Comment: Hi, My problem is on the server side. Since my BackEnd exposes REST services i can't rely on the FrontEnd to do the job of restriction.

Comment: Before aswering a REST, the "server" has to check the security context. Some of security data is provided today in the signed/encrypted token and it works. But my problem is that the token size is getting bigger and bigger